# Windows batch command to display all network connections?

Tags: windows, networking, batch-file

What Windows (preferably XP) batch command will list all of the network connections that appear in the Network Connections dialog?  I've tried `RASDIAL`, `IPCONFIG`, `NETSTAT`, and `NET` commands with various option combinations, but they only seem to show those that are actually connected.  I want to see the ones not connected as well.

**CLARIFICATION:** I want to be able to see dialups, wireless, firewire, LAN, miniport, VPN, etc. connections whether connected, disconnected, disabled, etc. just like in the Network Connections dialog.

Comment: What "connections"? Maybe clarify? Physical? Logical? ipconfig /all displays physical, while netstat -a will display logical port connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this Windows script : [List Items in the Network Connections Folder](https://web.archive.org/web/20150514022917/http://www.thescriptlibrary.com/default.asp?Action=Display&Level=Category3&ScriptLanguage=VBScript&Category1=Desktop%20Management&Category2=Special%20Folders&Title=List%20Items%20in%20the%20Network%20Connections%20Folder):

```
Const NETWORK_CONNECTIONS = &H31;&

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(NETWORK_CONNECTIONS)
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
Wscript.Echo objFolderItem.Path

Set colItems = objFolder.Items
For Each objItem in colItems
    Wscript.Echo objItem.Name
Next
```

> **Description:** Reports the path to the Network Connections folder, and then lists any items found in that folder. For Windows NT 4.0 and
>   Windows 98, this script requires Windows Script Host 5.1 and Internet
>   Explorer 4.0 or later.

Comment: Nice find.  On my machine, it only shows: `
::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\::{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309
}\::{7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}
Local Area Connection`, which is 2 less than netsh, but I don't have any disconnected connections to try it on.

Comment: The link does not apply anymore. :(

Comment: @dolmen: It worked for me just now.

Comment: @harrymc That link seems to be broken. Can you please (if possible) post the script here? Or are you aware of any other solution(s) by now?

Comment: @baburao: Link replaced from the Wayback Machine and script copied into the answer. Remember that this is a very old post and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ipconfig /all` doesn't list your disconnected devices?

**Update**

You might try [netsh](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html) - it's an interactive program.  Type netsh.  At the prompt try:

```
> interface show interface

> bye   (or quit)
```

I don't have a disconnected interface my self to try this on, sorry in advance.

Comment: I believe he wants to include things like dialup connections, 1394 connections, and other non-TCP/IP connections.

Comment: Nope.  At the moment, Network Connections shows 1 Internet Connection, 5 LAN connections, and 1 VPN connection.  `ipconfig /all` shows only the 3 connections that are actively connected.

Comment: netsh shows almost everything, but not the VPN connection.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this from a batch file?

```
NetSh Interface httpstunnel Show Interfaces
NetSh Interface IPv4 Show Interfaces
NetSh Interface IPv6 Show Interfaces
```